# Rolling Mean Legend Labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to plot the rolling mean on a double-axis graph. However, I am unable to create my legend correctly. Any pointers?

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

# df6 = t100df5.rolling(window=12).mean()
lns1 = ax1.plot(
     df6,
    label = ['Alpha', 'Beta'],         # how do I add 'Beta' label correctly?
    linewidth = 2.0)


lns2 = ax2.plot(temp,
                label = 'Dollars',
                color='black')

lns = lns1+lns2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
L = ax1.legend(lns, labs, loc = 0, frameon = True)
```

df6 looks like this:

```
          Alpha    Beta
TIME        
1990-01-01  NaN     NaN
1990-02-01  NaN     NaN
1990-03-01  NaN     NaN
1990-04-01  NaN     NaN
1990-05-01  NaN     NaN
...     ...     ...
2019-08-01  10.012447   8.331901
2019-09-01  9.909044    8.263813
2019-10-01  9.810155    8.185539
2019-11-01  9.711690    8.085016
2019-12-01  9.619968    8.03533
```

And temp looks like this:

```
             Dollars
date    
1994-01-01  NaN
1994-02-01  NaN
1994-03-01  225.664248
1994-04-01  217.475670
1995-01-01  216.464499
...     ...
2018-04-01  179.176545
2019-01-01  177.624369
2019-02-01  178.731035
2019-03-01  176.624608
2019-04-01  177.357060
```

Note that the datetime objects are the indices for the dataframes.

**How can I add a legend with appropriate labels for the graph below?** The black line is from temp and both of the other lines are from df6.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added another ax1.plot statement like this:

```py
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

lns1 = ax1.plot(
     df6.index, df6.Alpha
    label = 'Alpha',
    linewidth = 2.0)

lns1_5 = ax1.plot(df6.index, df6.Beta, label = 'Beta')

lns2 = ax2.plot(temp,
                label = 'Dollars',
                color='black')

lns = lns1+lns1_5+lns2
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns]
L = ax1.legend(lns, labs, loc = 0, frameon = True)
```